# How can I recall commands from bash_history in vim?

Tags: vim, history

I'm aware of that vim is just an editor, but I sometimes want to call bash commands within vim like following:

```
:!some --long --command -I --do --not --remember
```

So recalling from history is a vital function for me to edit things.
Both of `cnoremap <C-p> <Up>` and `cnoremap <C-n> <Down>` are always sitting in my `.vimrc`.

Now I'm wondering if I can search not only `$HOME/.viminfo` but also `$HOME/.bash_history` (with prepending `:!`).

Can I do like that without vim plugins?

Comment: I think you could define a command `:Bash` that acts like `:!`, and then define a custom completion for it that looks in `.bash_history`.  Would that count as "without vim plugins"?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Few hosts I have are isolated from the internet, it just makes me keep back away from these plugin managers.  Would you happen to have some references related creating completion in vimscript?

Comment: I am suggesting adding a few lines (maybe a dozen or two) to define a function and a command in your vimrc file.  You would not have to mess with plugin managers, but it might be considered equivalent to writing your own plugin.  The reference is `:help :command-completion-custom`.  The example `:Finger` command and `ListUsers()` completion function are not that far from what you want; four lines total.

Comment: @benjifisher, great! Thank you for the reference.  I'll check it later.

Comment: @ernix It's a nice idea.  Please stick it on github when you're done! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about making it so that when Vim is launched it will read in ~/.bash_history and append it to the appropriate section in .viminfo (which stores command-history, among other things)? To avoid duplicating the entire Bash history on later launches of Vim you should run a snippet of script to remove duplicate lines.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  It indeed sounds much simpler, I should've tried it first.